# What is the difference between @Controller and @RequestMapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have following code in my MVC;

```
...
...
@Controller
public class HelloController{

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView sayHelloMethod(){
.....
```

I hit the URI `localhostXXXXX\root\hello.htm` and DispatcherServlet searched and maps to this handler i.e @Controller class and call the "/hello" mapped method. I am not able to understand is how DispatcherServlet maps to sayHelloWorldMethod?

*I tried to change both class name and @RequestMapping String name and only when both of them contains "hello" String, this example works else not.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Controller will make the class which is annotated to act as controller, in simple words, the dispatcher servlet will look for the path you specified in all the bean classes initialised on startup.

@Requestmapping will make the request mapped to destined method. Suppose, if my URI is like this http://localhost:8080/Home/Hello.

and my code in controller is:

```
@controller
class Hello extends .... {

   @RequestMapping("Home/Hello")
   public .... sayHello() {
      /* your code here
      */
   }
}
```

Here Home/Hello is what is mentioned with @RequestMapping annotation. So the Dispatcher will search and map your request to sayHello method in the controller.

Comment: at what point of time BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping comes in picture?

Comment: When Doing Uri Request, RequestHandler will get its work.

Comment: The DispatcherServlet will initialise all your bean classes in your project. So when you hit any request in a client say browser, then the dispatcher servlet will check fr the bean with the URI mapped to a request. After finding the path, the DispatcherServlet will call the Requesthandler to do the job, means to request the uri and to get the response. If response comes without an error, the view in which the response should be displayed will be identified and passes the data to view say HTML page. Thats how the flow works.

Comment: "check fr the bean with the URI mapped to a request", could you explain it a little?you mean DispatchercServlet checks for Controllers containing @RequestMappings with URI patterns ?

Comment: It scans all the controllers and it finds the specified URI then do the work as mmentioned.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the name of the controller itself doesn't matter. The @Controller annotation is used to mark this component as a controller to be used latter in mapping api calls.

While as for the @RequestMapping is used to set the endpoint url of the annotated method, which means that you could change the name of the method (sayHelloMethod) as you want. So setting the @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET) will map the "/hello" url with the GET request to this method.

So the only name matters here is the name of the @RequestMapping url

Comment: at what point of time BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping comes in picture?

Comment: @Goutham.T.J Could you help me understanding the flow from URL get in browser to sayHello method call?

Comment: @Goutham.T.J actually I want to ask how

Comment: At the beginning of the application all beans must have been initialized, so if you don't annotate the Bean "HelloController" as a controller, then it will never be loaded by the application.
UrlMapping will map the request to the url in the @RequestMapping

Comment: @Goutham.T.J Actually I want to know how "BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping " works in this scenario

Comment: @AmrAlaa How handlerMapping picks up the right controller during call?

Comment: It will search for the "RequestMapping" in any annotated "Controller." You can specify a url for this controller 
https://springframework.guru/spring-requestmapping-annotation/